# Deleting all objects in an association

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, ember.js, ember-data

Given a model that looks something like this:

```
App.Parent = Ember.Model.extend(
    children: DS.attr.hasMany('App.Child')
)

App.Child = Ember.Model.extend(
    parent: DS.attr.belongsTo('App.Parent')
)

parent = App.Parent.find(1)

# How do I remove parent and all of it's children?
# This doesn't work since I'm removing elements from an array while iterating it
parent.get('children').forEach( c -> c.deleteRecord() )
parent.deleteRecord()

# Only removing the parent like this won't work either, 
# Ember-data generates some strange PUT requests for every child
parent.deleteRecord()

# I guess I could do this, but it feels really awkward and 
# wrong to use the adapter directly.
# And it also side-steps transactions making bulk updates impossible
App.store.adapter.deleteRecords(App.store, App.Child, parent.get('children'))
parent.deleteRecord()
App.store.commit()
```

Is there a more straight-forward way and what are the strange PUT requests that are generated when only deleting the parent?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps using the toArray() method http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ArrayProxy.html#method_toArray should work because your are no more modifying directly the ManyArray

```
parent.get('children').toArray().forEach( c -> c.deleteRecord() )
```

For the strange PUT request on the children, it's because when deleting the parent, ember-data "nullifies" the parent property on the children.

Answer (score 0):

Plain JavaScript instead of CoffeeScript, but I think you'll be able to convert:

```
var children = parent.get('children'),
    i = children.length;

while (i--) {
    children[i].deleteRecord();
}
```